# C++ std::out_of_range vector::_M_range_check

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I ve got this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#define NMax 100

using namespace std;

vector <int> v(100);
int n;

FILE* in = freopen("input.in", "r", stdin);
FILE* out = freopen("output.out", "w", stdout);

void afiseaza(){
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        fprintf(out, "%d", v.at(i));
    }
    fprintf(out, "\n");
}

void bkt(int i){
    if(i == n + 1) afiseaza();
    else{
        int i, j;
        for(j = v.at(i-1); j <= n; j++){
            v.at(i) = j;
        }
        bkt(i+1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    fscanf(in, "%d", &n);
    bkt(1);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

It throws std::out_of_range error and i can't understand why, the size of the vector is in the bounds. Tryed to find more about error, but can't find the problem on my code
Ty for your time

Comment: `the size of the vector is in the bounds` clearly not.

Comment: since you have condition `<=n`, then that means `n` must be at most 99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as a separate answer, because it's a completely separate thing from my first suggestion. In the loop in `bkt`, you declare a new, locallly scoped `i`, which hides the function parameter and has an undefined value. Using this `i` is probably why you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Vector indices are 0-based, the valid values are 0 through size-1. If I trace your code correctly, you access index - 1 in the very first call to `bkt` if you input 0 or less for `n`, and then index size in `afiseaza`.

I suggest you use a debugger to step through your code and observe the values as you go.

Comment: sry, originally i said bkt(1), but i edited so many times. The error is still there. Afiseaza was made for numbers between 1 and n

Comment: I stand by my suggestion of the debugger. You are reaching an `at()` call with a bad value and you need to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

The very first time your code tries to access `v`, it calls `v.at(-1)`. This is clearly out of bounds.

Comment: sry, originally i said bkt(1), but i edited so many times. The error is still there.